# Tutorial for horizontal scrolling single page site

Tags: css-float, horizontalscrollview

I'm having trouble finding some good resources or even an example of the kind of site I'm trying to build.

Essentially it is a one page, horizontally scrolling site with a fixed header and footer at the top and bottom. Rather than scroll using buttons or a scroll bar, clicking on the links in the nav menu would move the page across, most likely using jQuery, to the respective section.

In other words, just for clarity, the header, footer and background always remain in place and it is the main content section which moves left and right. So there would be half a dozen or so floated divs stacked in a single row.

I have that basic framework laid out, but I can't figure out how to allow the main content section to extend past the window size, allowing for all these divs to float in a line.

Here is a crude/minimalist demo of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/U8ZYT/

I would appreciate any links to tutorials, examples of similar websites or any direct suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using jcarousel..its pretty easy to make it do exactly what your loking for and theyve got some pretty good examples to get you started

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm working to implement it now. Do you happen to know how to make it to that each list item is set to the window width?